# Permissions with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I was looking for an addin/extension for Microsoft Planner to do Gantt charts, and came across [this Chrome extension](https://www.jijitechnologies.com/blogs/introducing-planner-ganttchart-timeline-scheduler-agenda-view-in-apps4pro).  I realised that Planner must have an API in order to do this, and I had been wanting a project to play around and learn more about APIs so I decided I would build my own wee PHP app to pull a Plan and put it into a Gantt chart (and maybe do some other fun stuff too).

All was going well, I could log in, pull my name etc but when I tried to access Plans, I got error messages.  According to the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and [the API reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/plannerplan_get) I don't have the appropriate permissions to pull plan details (Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All).

However, the linked extension above does work for me and I am able to see all my plans so surely there is another way to get the data?  Is there some other Planner API I have overlooked? Or some other method of extracting that data other than the Graph API?  Any help appreciated, I'm new to playing around with APIs etc...

Answer (score 0):

> However, the linked extension above does work for me and I am able to
>   see all my plans so surely there is another way to get the data? Is
>   there some other Planner API I have overlooked? Or some other method
>   of extracting that data other than the Graph API? Any help
>   appreciated, I'm new to playing around with APIs etc...

1. Now the official way is get the data by [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/planner_overview), still in development(beta)
2. Old Microsoft planner api will be replaced by the latest Planner Graph API. So you don't need to find other resource.
3. No.

What you need to do is researching on Permission Config for your requirement.

Comment: Are you able to expand a little more on the Permission Config? I cant change my permissions (my account is with a large multinational, that's way above my pay grade).  As this other app is able to access my data (presumably using the API) is it about how I configure my request?

Comment: Check the permission in http://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-integrate-apps-with-azure-ad. Use which one should based on your requirement.